# Amazon SQS, How to send message into other person Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I would like to create a small messaging(Sending/Receiving) system using Amazon SQS, My question is, eg: if I logged-in to SQS, and created a message, and I would like to submit/post this message to another person queue? is this possible ? If Yes, how we can do that.

What my whole scenario is

1. Submit message into Other User SQS & trigger notification using SNS.
2. Once User read that message, remove it from SQS and sync into User
3. S3 Bucket. Read S3 Bucket and show messages in chat form.

Comment: what do you mean by 'another person queue', 'Other User SQS' or 'sync into User'?

Comment: @ketan I would like to create chat system, like send/receive messages, Please read my mentioned scenario in question.

Comment: Your scenario needs clarification.  Do you mean SQS queues in different accounts or does each user have their own queue?  Typically you use SNS to send messages into an SQS queue, not the other way around so the purpose of this needs clarified.  What is the user you are syncing into?  How is S3 related to this and what is the "chat" you are referring to?

Comment: @JaredHatfield Yes, from SQS means, Queues in different account, and from chat means, Consider the real time chat (communication messages). would this possible through Using SQS and S3 Bucket ???

Comment: It is possible to grant access to AWS resources cross accounts.  The specifics as to what you are wanting to accomplish are a little unclear though.  That said, I've seen SNS topics used for cross account communication more than SQS as SNS gives the user of the other account flexibility in how they can process the message leaving options such as AWS Lambda available.